# MongoDB lookup when foreign field is an array of ids

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections, fruit and salesman . I want my query to return all fruit with comma separated salesman.

Salesman document have array of fruit id

fruit document have id, name ,........
salesman table have id,name, fruits[apple_id,mango_id.......],...

```
db.getCollection('fruit').aggregate([{ "$unwind": "$fruits" }, { "$lookup": {
       "from": "salesman",
       "localField": "fruits",
       "foreignField": "_id",
       "as": "fruitObjects"
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$fruitObjects" } ])
```

even this query is not giving result of $fruitObjects..?

Fruit Document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba32eb"),
    "name" : "Mango"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba32ec"),
    "name" : "Pears"
}

{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba32de"),
    "name" : "apple"
}

{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba32fe"),
    "name" : "guava"
}
```

Salesman document

```````````````````````````
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba3257"),
    "name" : "xyz",
    "fruits":["5b101caddcab7850a4ba32ec","5b101caddcab7850a4ba32de","5b101caddcab7850a4ba32fe"]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba3258"),
    "name" : "abc",
    "fruits":["5b101caddcab7850a4ba32eb","5b101caddcab7850a4ba32de"]
}

{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba3259"),
    "name" : "def",
    "fruits":["5b101caddcab7850a4ba32ec"]
}

{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba3260"),
    "name" : "zxc",
    "fruits":["5b101caddcab7850a4ba32ec","5b101caddcab7850a4ba32de","5b101caddcab7850a4ba32eb"]
}
``````````````````````````
```````````````````````````

Comment: Please provide examples of documents from both collections.

Comment: Example of both document i have added .Please find it.

Comment: @srinivasy thanks for details explanation. it is working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes @barrypicker is correct - types of fields didn't match which is resulting in empty on `salesman`, Please try to store both of same type. Meanwhile you can actually convert one to other type - while querying each time, Also you need not to do `$unwind`, Please try below query :

**Query 1:**

```
db.fruit.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "salesman",
            let: { fruitName: { $toString: '$_id' } },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match:
                    {
                        $expr:
                            { $in: ["$$fruitName", "$fruits"] }
                    }
                }, { $project: { name: 1, _id: 0 } }
            ],
            as: "salesman"
        }
    }])
```

**Result for Query 1:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba32eb"),
    "name" : "Mango",
    "salesman" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "abc"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "zxc"
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba32ec"),
    "name" : "Pears",
    "salesman" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "def"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "zxc"
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba32de"),
    "name" : "apple",
    "salesman" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "abc"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "zxc"
        }
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba32fe"),
    "name" : "guava",
    "salesman" : []
}
```

Or if you want those names to be in an array :

**Query 2 :**

```
db.fruit.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "salesman",
            let: { fruitName: { $toString: '$_id' } },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match:
                    {
                        $expr:
                            { $in: ["$$fruitName", "$fruits"] }
                    }
                }, { $project: { name: 1, _id: 0 } }
            ],
            as: "salesmanList"
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
            name: 1, salesman: {
                $map:
                {
                    input: "$salesmanList",
                    as: "each",
                    in: '$$each.name'
                }
            }
        }
    }])
```

**Result for Query 2:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba32eb"),
    "name" : "Mango",
    "salesman" : [ 
        "abc", 
        "zxc"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba32ec"),
    "name" : "Pears",
    "salesman" : [ 
        "def", 
        "zxc"
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba32de"),
    "name" : "apple",
    "salesman" : [ 
        "abc", 
        "zxc"
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba32fe"),
    "name" : "guava",
    "salesman" : []
}
```

**fruit collection :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba32eb"),
    "name" : "Mango"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba32ec"),
    "name" : "Pears"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba32de"),
    "name" : "apple"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba32fe"),
    "name" : "guava"
}
```

**salesman collection :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba3258"),
    "name" : "abc",
    "fruits" : [ 
        "5b101caddcab7850a4ba32eb", 
        "5b101caddcab7850a4ba32de"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba3259"),
    "name" : "def",
    "fruits" : [ 
        "5b101caddcab7850a4ba32ec"
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b101caddcab7850a4ba3260"),
    "name" : "zxc",
    "fruits" : [ 
        "5b101caddcab7850a4ba32ec", 
        "5b101caddcab7850a4ba32de", 
        "5b101caddcab7850a4ba32eb"
    ]
}
```

If you want the entire object from `salesman` then you could remove `{ $project: { name: 1, _id: 0 } }` in `$lookup`.

**Ref :** [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#examples), [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html#examples)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
db.salesman.aggregate([
  { $unwind : "$fruits" },
  { $addFields : { "fruitObjectId": { $toObjectId: "$fruits" } } },
  { $lookup : {
      "from" : "fruit",
      "localField" : "fruitObjectId",
      "foreignField" : "_id",
      "as" : "fruitObjects"
    }
  } 
])
```

Or, perhaps from the opposite perspective?

```
db.fruit.aggregate([
  { $project : {
      _id : { $toString : "$_id" },
      name : 1
    }
  },
  { $lookup : {
      "from" : "salesman",
      "localField" : "_id",
      "foreignField" : "fruits",
      "as" : "fruitObjects"      
    }
  }
])
```